# Using robotics sx for our robotics software framework

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I am one of the maintainers of the [Rock](http://rock-robotics.org/stable/) (Robot Construction Kit) Software framework. We thought about opening our own Q&A site. I would say it might be around 50 people or so, and the questions would be quite software related. But since all questions are very robotic related, what do you guys think about if we used the robotics sx site for our Q&A?

Comment: Let me just echo [Mark's sentiments](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/a/229/131). We'd be very happy indeed to have Rock questions here and are looking forward to your developers and users joining our community.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any problem whatsoever with Robotics Stack Exchange hosting *Rock* questions.

**In fact, we'd love to have you aboard.**

All that we ask is that you respect the guidelines for [writing good questions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [writing good answers](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), avoid questions which are not [on topic](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and which [aren't a good fit for stack exchange sites](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in general.

I would highly recommend that people who are not regulars of other Stack Exchange sites [take the tour](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/about) before they dive in. It doesn't take long and helps people understand a little of how Stack Exchange works and why.

I look forward to starting to see *Rock* questions on *Robotics*.